# Automator Quick Action - Run AppleScript on each item in folder

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to build a Quick Action in Automator that I can run on any folder, which would run the following AppleScript on each of the .pdf files inside that folder one by one - waiting for the first to finish, before starting again on the next file.

Currently I have only the AppleScript code that I want to run, but I can't figure out how to attach it to a Quick Action and make it run the code on each pdf item inside.

Note: The number of PDF files in the folder can be different each time.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set theFile to input's item 1

    set theSeconds to time of (current date)

    tell application "Finder"
        set theDuplicate to duplicate file "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:IddTest:template.indd"
    end tell

    tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020" to open file (theDuplicate as string)

    tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
        if document 1 exists then
            repeat 34 times
                tell document 1
                    relink link "placeholder.pdf" to theFile
                    try
                        update link "placeholder.pdf"
                    end try
                end tell
            end repeat
        end if
    
        close document 1 saving yes
    end tell

    tell application "Finder"
        set name of theDuplicate to "" & theSeconds & ".indd"
    end tell

end run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I do not have **Adobe InDesign 2020** so my rework of your **AppleScript** *code* has not been tested, however I believe it should work.

- In **Automator** create a new *workflow* as a **Quick Action**  with setting as shown in the image below.
- Add a **Get Folder Contents** *action*.
- Add a **Filter Finder Items** *action* with setting as shown in the image below.
- Add a **Run AppleScript** *action* replacing the default *code* with the **AppleScript** *code* below.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}

    repeat with thisFile in input

        set theSeconds to time of (current date)

        tell application "Finder"
            set theDuplicate to duplicate file "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:IddTest:template.indd"
        end tell

        tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
            open file (theDuplicate as string)
            delay 2
            if document 1 exists then
                repeat 34 times
                    tell document 1
                        relink link "placeholder.pdf" to thisFile
                        try
                            update link "placeholder.pdf"
                        end try
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end if
            close document 1 saving yes
        end tell

        tell application "Finder"
            set name of theDuplicate to "" & theSeconds & ".indd"
        end tell
    
    end repeat

end run
```

---

[image]